# Spring - yaml and .properties configurations

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

i've been working with Spring for some time and have a question regarding the very common configuration properties files (like the common `application.properties` that comes with every spring boot app you initialize). Recently, i also found that configurations like this can be done in yaml files. I have two questions:

1. When in a `application.properties` file, we write something like:

```py
# application.properties

spring.debug = true
some-random-value = 15
```

does this mean that these values will be injected in the application context?

2. When we write something like:

```py
# application.properties

spring.debug = true
```

does this mean, that somewhere, there is some class, that has an attribute that looks something like this? -->

```java
@Component
class SomeClass{

@Value("spring.debug")
boolean shouldIRunInDebugMode;

...
}
```

2.a. If the answer to question 2 is yes, then how can I, looking at something like this:

```py
# application.properties

spring.debug = true
```

find that class that is expecting that value. The same would apply to if i was looking at something like:

```yaml
# application.yaml

someThidPartyLibraryName:
   shouldWeLog: true
```

If i see a yaml configuration file, just looking at all the configuration there usually is not enough for me to know what is happening. How can i find the class that is being affected by this configuration, so that i can better understand what this config is doing?

Thank you!

Comment: You can check the @EnableAutoConfiguration annotation. There are 2/3 config classes defined to be imported. They bootstrap the autoconfig feature. from there and if you have the source code attached, you can trace down the Autoconfig classes and the Bean class related to each third-party lib for which Spring has an integration

Comment: The loading up of specific beans with the config defined in your props or yml file depends on the @Conditional annotations which came with Spring 4

Comment: As an example - when you say h2.console.path.enabled -> There is a corresponding class H2ConsoleProperties and H2ConsoleAutoConfiguration which works with these properties. Similar for DataSource.

Comment: All the model and config classes are under autoconfigure package. I started tracing and understanding the code like this. Let me know if you found a better way to sniff around the src code

Comment: Hey @PriyakDey, im not sure what you mean by `There are 2/3 config classes defined to be imported.` I am currently looking at the `public @interface EnableAutoConfiguration`, but im not sure where to go from here to find any of the actual classes. Also wouldn't this only work for classes that are configured using ` @ConfigurationProperties` ?

Comment: The bootstrap config classes are defined/imported using the Import annotation. Check the meta annotation @Import on top of EnableAutoConfiguration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding regarding spring value injections from application.properties is correct. #2 - is Yes. Any property from application.properties can be injected to any java class as @Value.

Regarding #2.a - Yaml is just another format on how you organize your variable hierarchy by indentations. That's a superset to the JSON structure.

## For example,

in application.properties file you can add something like this

 `myapp.db.url=<dburl>
 myapp.db.username=<dbuser>
 myapp.db.password=<dbpassword>`

the same can be represented in Yaml in a much efficient manner as below

`myapp:
  db:
    url:<dburl>
    username:<dbuser>
    password:<dbpassword>`

And in either case, for your Jave file you can inject as

`@Value("myapp.db.url"
private String dbUrl;`

Answer (score 2):

The response is generally yes. If you declare a property in the `application.properties` or `application.yaml` is mainly, because you would use it later in the code, for example injecting in some bean with the support of `@Value` annotation. However, there are also many built-in properties (let's say for example `server.port`), which you usually don't have to declare and therefore you won't see explicitly in the code. Use an IDE to search the configuration properties and the manual to check the preconfigured ones in case of need.

Answer (score 1):

Properties defined in yaml or a properties file may be accessed using the `@Value` annotation to inject, or using a `@ConfigurationProperties` class - see https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config-typesafe-configuration-properties for complete details.

Finding the property usage is supported by some IDEs - IntelliJ allows you to click through. Otherwise it's a search through the source. For `@ConfigurationProperties`, once you find the class then just look for code that calls its accessor methods.

Comment: Yep, thanks for the answer. Looks like the my IDE is not very good at finding classes that i have as dependencies that are using configurations which are written in my project.

Answer (score 1):

Properties files and yaml files are used in Spring Boot for configurations. The main difference between the two is yaml provides structuring/grouping of configurations where as Properties are usually flat and may be repeating the same information:

For example;

Properties file

```
server.port = 8080
server.host = localhost
```

yaml file

```
server:
  port: 8080
  host: localhost
```

But in a Spring Boot AutoConfiguration class regardless of yaml or Properties used, a following looking ConfigurationProperties class will be used which will map `server.port` and `server.host`

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "server")
public class ServerConfiguration {

    private int port;
    private String host;

}

@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(ServerConfiguration.class)
public class ServerAutoConfiguration {

}
```

Hope this answers your questions.